# Moving the boot partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I have the current situation:

[image: Dem partitions]

As you can see there is a 500mb chunck to the left of the boot partition that I would like to recover.

The final setup I want is:

[image: Final Situation]

where I am leaving 22gb left to my linux root partition as I might want to  use some of the extra space to install different distro.

Question is: if I move the boot partition I get warnings telling me that this might make the system unbootable. Is there a way or a better order to perform this work with partitions, so as to minimize the risk of reboot? I should move the big partition and the root partition first, and then move the boot? or viceversa? or some other way?

Comment: Whatever you do, you should/need to do from a live system (boot from the Ubuntu install DVD/USB). I think you should not get any problems normally, but having `boot-repair` at hand could be useful though. Anyways - make a backup and you never have to worry about a thing!

Comment: I am using my live CD to do all this repartitioning.

Comment: First thing, as I launch gparted to obtain the configuration, gparted crashes and now I am left with a black /dev/sda2 of 800mb, with a red exclamation mark. How do I go back?

Comment: What is the meaning of a black partition? It should describe this somewhere.

Comment: It means, according to gparted formatting menu: cleared ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, ***any*** partitioning operation is at least a little risky. You should ***always*** have backups and a recovery plan in case of data loss or a loss of bootability.

In the BIOS arena, moving a partition can render it unbootable because many boot loaders rely on absolute sector values to locate more complex parts of themselves. If that sector is in a partition that moves, the reference is unlikely to be updated, and the boot will fail. Details vary from one boot loader to another, though, which makes predicting the results of moving a partition difficult. In your case, you're not using BIOS, which means that BIOS rules don't apply. Unfortunately, there's an EFI issue that can be almost as pernicious: Under EFI, boot loader information is stored in NVRAM. These entries point to boot loaders by using various types of information, including a filename, a partition GUID, a partition number, and a disk hardware identifying code. Most of these things will not change when you move your partition, but its partition number might change.

You could protect yourself against this possibility in various ways. The simplest might be to create a small (say, 1MiB) partition before your current `/dev/sda2`. That way, if GParted (or some other tool) decides to number your partitions in a rising sequence, your current `/dev/sda2` will remain `/dev/sda2` (or the EFI's equivalent of that). Another thing you could do would be to use the transpose feature of `gdisk` (the `t` option on the experts' menu) to swap partition numbers, should your current `/dev/sda2` become `/dev/sda1`. (Note that you can swap an existing partition number with an empty one, so this can work even if there ends up being no `/dev/sda2`.) In either case, though, you should be proactive -- some EFIs completely delete boot entries that are invalid, so if your partition numbers change and you try to boot, the entries may be lost and you'll have to re-create them. Check your partition numbers *before* rebooting, and if your ESP is no longer `/dev/sda2`, take action immediately.

Personally, I think it would be easier (and cleaner) to plan to restore your boot loader(s). You've probably got GRUB installed now, so you could use [Boot Repair,](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) which usually does a decent job restoring GRUB setups. If you install another couple of OSes, Boot Repair might or might not do as good a job -- but then, if you install another OS, it will install its own boot loader/manager, which might do what you need. (If it *doesn't* do what you need, you'll have to take action to fix it, since the new OS will almost certainly set its boot loader as the default one.) Another option and generally useful backup is having my [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) installed on a USB flash drive. It can help boot in an emergency situation, since it relies less on configuration files than most boot loaders. If the GRUB setup starts getting confused by having too many OSes, rEFInd might do a better job as your regular boot manager, too -- but that's a matter of both personal preference and what works well in particular situations.