# Installed Ubuntu, overwrote GPT boot record, how best to restore?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, bootloader, gpt

I've installed Ubuntu 17.04 on my laptop, on an ultrashort USB stick which stays in place most of the time. I had meant to leave the Windows 10 (GPT-formatted drive) boot record untouched and to just switch boot devices in the BIOS.

It looks like I forgot to specify that during installation though and as a result I can still boot Windows when I have the USB stick in but when I take it out I just get a grub2 prompt.

From what I see, recreating the Windows boot record with Windows tooling will require some rescue/boot media which I don't have handy so I was wondering if there is some way to restore the Windows GPT boot record from a backup (if indeed Ubuntu does create such a thing during installation).

Comment: Ubuntu assumes you know what you are doing and have already made your own backups and reviewed some instructions on installing. But if Windows 10 and UEFI, you have a UEFI boot menu, often f10 or f12 that should let you directly boot Windows. Was Windows 10 originally installed?  If drive is gpt then Windows 10 must be UEFI.

Comment: GRUB is installed partly on the HDD and partly on the USB stick. That's why when you pull the stick, GRUB breaks. If you can boot to Windows, you might be able to fix the MBR in an administrative command prompt window using the `fixmbr` command. Search here on AU for "fixmbr". Lastly... don't run Ubuntu from a USB stick... install it on the HDD.

Comment: @oldfred Well, I sort of know what I'm doing but I'm an old man and it looks as though my concentration has lapsed in this instance. Yes, Windows was originally installed. Note I still can boot both Windows and Ubuntu when the USB stick is plugged in, are you suggesting that without it I should be able to as well? And actually you're making a great point on backups, I have a dd of the whole SSD that I probably took before installing Ubuntu, so all I likely need to do is copy the first x kB over...

Comment: @heynnema Not sure about fixmbr since it's a UEFI/GPT partitioned SSD. I thought people talk about GPT and MBR as two entirely different things so a program called fixmbr seems unlikely to help. My googling suggests it would have to be something like `bootrec /FixBoot... oh, and it looks like this can be done without separate recovery media in Win10: http://www.dell.com/support/article/uk/en/ukbsdt1/SLN300987/how-to-repair-the-efi-bootloader-on-a-gpt-hdd-for-windows-7--8--81-and-10-on-your-dell-pc?lang=EN I'll report back in the next few days.

Comment: @thomanski you're probably right... bootrec... never claimed to be a Windows expert :-)

Comment: With UEFI, both Windows & Ubuntu's initial boot files are in the ESP - efi system partition on sda. You cannot use dd to restore the MBR as UEFI does not use gpt's protective MBR. Often better to just have file copies. And with external USB, grub still installs boot files to ESP on sda, but rest of grub is installed in external. Did you partition external with gpt and include an ESP on it? That is required to boot external and you have to copy files into manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BIOS/CSM/legacy-mode and EFI/UEFI-mode booting work quite differently. In particular, you have almost certainly *not* overwritten any Windows boot records or files. Rather, you've simply set GRUB to be the default boot loader; but as GRUB relies on files stored on the USB flash drive, the result is that GRUB won't work correctly unless the USB flash drive is plugged in. There are several ways to solve this problem, including (but not necessarily limited to):

- **Install another boot manager** -- Some non-GRUB boot managers don't rely on files stored off the [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition). For instance, my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) should work well for you. If you install rEFInd and make it the default boot program, you'll see rEFInd every time you boot, but you'll still be able to boot Windows even when the USB flash drive is unplugged. One possible complication is Secure Boot; if it's enabled, you'll need to enroll one or two Secure Boot keys using the non-user-friendly MokManager user interface the first time you boot. See the [rEFInd Secure Boot documentation](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/secureboot.html) for details. In theory, you could use the Windows boot manager as the default boot program; but I don't know offhand how to configure it to chainload to GRUB. If you want to pursue this option, I suggest you ask about it on a Windows forum.
- **Use the built-in boot manager** -- Your computer likely comes with a built-in boot manager, which you can use to bypass GRUB and boot Windows. Details of how to use this vary from one computer to another, though. Typically, you must hit Esc, Enter, or a function key when you power on the computer; but which key to hit varies from one system to another. You could do this just to boot Windows, or you could change the default (via `efibootmgr` in Ubuntu or [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) in Windows) to boot Windows and then use the built-in boot manager only when you want to boot Windows.
- **Move `/boot`** -- The GRUB configuration files are in the `/boot/grub` directory, so one way to handle this is to create a small (~500-1000MB) `/boot` partition on your computer's internal hard disk. This will keep GRUB working even when the USB drive is unplugged. This is most easily done during Ubuntu installation, so if you're willing to re-install, you might try it. You can also do it after installing Ubuntu, but this will require moving files around and then re-installing GRUB. See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/640497/moving-the-boot-partition) for a bit more on this possibility.
- **Reconfigure GRUB** -- It's possible to reconfigure GRUB to not rely on files in the Linux `/boot` directory. This is an advanced topic, though. [This wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFIBooting) describes this sort of advanced GRUB configuration. (Note that the page describes itself as outdated and refers to another one; but the new page lacks the details needed for this approach.) Note that if you do this, the default GRUB configuration scripts will no longer keep `grub.cfg` updated, so you'll need to handle that yourself, which means more ongoing maintenance effort on your part. Overall, I don't recommend you try this approach; I mention it only for the sake of completeness.

Note that *no* reconfiguration within Windows should be necessary, with some possible exceptions:

- You might use EasyUEFI to adjust the default boot order, as noted earlier.
- If you want to use the Windows boot manager to control the boot process, as noted earlier, you'll need to reconfigure it within Windows.
- If you haven't [disabled Fast Startup](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html) and [disabled Hibernate,](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2859-hibernate-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html) though, you should do that. These features make dual-booting dangerous because they can lead to filesystem damage. This has nothing to do with your USB-based Ubuntu installation, though.

Comment: Thank you ever so much for the awesome answer and for rEFInd, too. All I had to do was booting into Ubuntu, run a `sudo apt-get install refind`, was asked during installation whether I wanted to allow it to be written to the ESP and to take control (or something to that effect) which I gladly accepted and now I can easily boot with or without the USB stick.

Comment: I should add that I'm frequently experiencing [boot coups](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootcoup.html). This does not seem to be restricted to grub updates (unless I've had four of them without my knowledge) but it's also not happening on every restart. I can't quite put my finger on it. `refind-install` fixes that though and I have now figured out that Fn+F12 takes me (on my Lenovo 3 11") to the built-in boot manager that you've mentioned, so there's always that alternative.

Comment: With frequent boot coups, you might consider putting a call to `refind-mkdefault` in `/etc/rc.local`. That'll at least automate resetting rEFInd to the default boot manager once you boot Ubuntu. If the boot coups are being caused by something in Ubuntu, creating a link to `refind-mkdefault` in `/etc/rc6.d` may fix the problem.